# Fill Shapes/Icon In SVG Path (js)

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg.js

I have a SVG with path

```
<svg width="100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="transparent">
  <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
</svg>
```

[image: SVG Image]

and I have to fill some svg shapes / icons in the path with a `gap`. For example I have filled the svg path with the circle shape with a `gap=2px`

[image: SVG Edited Image]

is there any javascript function or can we do it with just SVGs and the `gap` between the circle should be customizable and it should work for all the svg with paths. (thanks in advance)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of filling you will need a special stroke. The `stroke-dasharray` is similar to the border-style in css. However it will create only dashed lines. In the following example I'm using `stroke-dasharray="0.1, 9.9"` meaning lines of 0.1 units and gaps of 9.9

To make them look like dotted I'm using stroke-linecap="round" and a thick line: `stroke-width="6"`

Please observe that line + gap = 0.1 + 9.9 = 10 and the square side length is 80 (a multiple of 10) ensuring that you have a dot in every corner.

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="transparent">
  <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" stroke-dasharray="0.1, 9.9" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" ></line>/>
</svg>
```

Comment: nice! but we can only get circle with it. I also need for [rectangle /triangle /any svg shapes] that should follow the path

Answer (score 2):

**Not using:**

- `<marker>`
- `getTotalLength` / `getPointAtLength`

**Using:**

- `<defs>` to define any (compound) **SVG group "markN"**
  in SVG these are global IDs in whole DOM page!
- a native JavaScript **Web Component** (JSWC) `<svg-path-markers>` to proces `<path>`
  `customElements.define` script can be executed **at any moment** you want!
- `<path marker="mark1" markers="4">` **attributes** indicating which markN to use
- a **unique ID** for each `<path>` to link it to an `<mpath>` (motionpath)
- `<animateMotion>` to *animate* a "marker"
- `keyPoints="0,${dist}"` to **position the "marker"**

**Output:**

[image]

**With:**

```html
<svg-path-markers>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="background:pink;max-height:180px">
    <defs>
      <g id="mark1"><circle fill="red"    cx="0" cy="0" r="8" /></g>
      <g id="mark2"><rect   fill="green"  x="-4" y="-4" width="8" height="8" /></g>
      <g id="mark3"><circle fill="yellow" cx="0" cy="0" r="2" /></g>
    </defs>
    <style>path{ stroke:green ; fill:none }</style>
    <path marker="mark1" markers="4"  d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" />
    <path marker="mark2" markers="8"  d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" />
    <path marker="mark3" markers="16" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" />
  </svg>
</svg-path-markers>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-path-markers", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML is parsed
        this.querySelectorAll("[marker]").forEach( path => {
          let duration = "2"; // set to 0.00001 for instant display
          let count = ~~path.getAttribute("markers") || 4;
          let id = path.id || (path.id = this.localName + Math.random()*1e9);
          let marker = dist => `<use href="#${path.getAttribute("marker")}">
                                <animateMotion 
                                   dur="${duration}" fill="freeze"calcMode="linear"
                                   keyPoints="0;${dist}" keyTimes="0;1" >
                                   <mpath href="#${id}"/>
                                 </animateMotion></use>`;
          path.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", Array(count).fill(0)
                                               .map((_,i) => marker(i*(1/count))).join(""));
        } )
      })}})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getTotalLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) to find the length of the path and [getPointAtLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) to find points along the path where you place the elements.

In this example I append `<use>` elements to a `<g>`.

```js
const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
const p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
const c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
const c2 = document.getElementById('c2');

setIcons(p1, 'r1', c1, 10);
setIcons(p2, 'p3', c2, 10);

function setIcons(path, id, container, numb){
  let total = parseInt(path.getTotalLength());
  let gap = total / numb;
  
  [...Array(numb).keys()].map(i => {
    let point = path.getPointAtLength(i*gap);
    let use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','use');
    use.setAttribute('href', `#${id}`);
    use.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${point.x} ${point.y})`);
    container.appendChild(use);
  });
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 220 100" height="100" stroke="black" fill="transparent">
  <defs>
    <rect id="r1" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="red" />
    <path id="p3" d="M -10 -12.5 A 5 5 90 0 0 10 -12.5 V 12.5 A 5 5 90 0 0 -10 12.5 Z" fill="red" />
  </defs>
  <path id="p1" d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" />
  <g id="c1"></g>
  <g transform="translate(120 0)">
    <path id="p2" d="m 0 90 V 50 A 1 1 1 0 1 90 50 V 90" />
    <g id="c2"></g>
  </g>
</svg>
```