# Apply a horizontal center to circles in SVG

Tags: html, svg

I try to center many circles inside a SVG but it's not working.

**My code :**

```html
<svg width="100%" height="20" style="background-color: green; text-align: center;">
<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="red" />
<circle cx="30" cy="10" r="10" fill="blue" />
<circle cx="50" cy="10" r="10" fill="grey" />
<circle cx="70" cy="10" r="10" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you explain me why 80 and 20 ? Because sometimes I'll get a number of circles providing by the database and I can not specify values, I need to generate them.

Comment: ViewBox "0 0 80 20" since 80 is the total width of you group of circles (4x20) . See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/RweZVGP). Please clarify, what you retrieve from the data base: number of circles, coordinates. Svg has only limited capabilities when it comes to fluid layouts - you might opt for a HTML/CSS (e.g by applying border-radius)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without math, but takes some fiddling of `keyPoints` in animateMotion,
which takes a **0;X** value between 0 and 1, and doesn't accept a percentage (alas)

Set `dur="0.0001s"` for "instant" display, a value of `0` does not animate

For dynamic creation of N `<circles>`, see the Web Component at: [Fill Shapes/Icon In SVG Path (js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198566/fill-shapes-icon-in-svg-path-js/75199633#75199633)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 20" style="background:green">
  <style>
    circle{ r:10 }
  </style>
  <path id="line" stroke="red" d="m0,10h200"></path>
  <circle fill="red">
    <animateMotion keyPoints="0;.25"   dur="0.00001s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#line"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <circle fill="yellow" >
    <animateMotion keyPoints="0;.50"   dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#line"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <circle fill="blue">
    <animateMotion keyPoints="0;.75"   dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyTimes="0;1"calcMode="linear">
      <mpath href="#line"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <g stroke="grey">
    <line x1="25%" y1="0" x2="25%" y2="100%"/>
    <line x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%"/>
    <line x1="75%" y1="0" x2="75%" y2="100%"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't need animations. Does your code works without animations ? And I don't want to drow lines...

Comment: Read the text, what does it say about animation? As for lines, maybe delete the ``line`` statements?