Staggering animation of SVG markers
Is it possible to stagger the animation of SVG markers to sync up with a line animation, i.e. so the markers become visible at the same time the line becomes visible behind it?
I've tried targeting the markers individually like this (below) which was unsuccessful:
.marker-circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}



<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  
 <defs>
   <marker class="marker" id="marker" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" refX="2" refY="2">
   <circle class="marker-circle" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" />
   </marker>
  </defs>
<style type="text/css">

.line {
  fill:none;
  fill-opacity:0.46;
  stroke:#3BB0FF;
  stroke-width:8;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  animation: draw 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
   
   
.marker-circle {
  fill:#FF4F4F;
  fill-opacity:0.0;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation: example 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {fill-opacity:0.0;}
  to {fill-opacity:1.0;}
}


.marker-circle:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 200ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 1000ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 1200ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 1400ms;
}

.marker-circle:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 1600ms;
}
    

</style>
<polygon class="line" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 
    153.38,388.49" marker-start="url(#marker)" marker-mid="url(#marker)"/>
</svg>




The spec explicitly forbids this: "The rendering effect of a marker is as if the contents of the referenced marker element were deeply cloned into a separate non-exposed DOM tree for each instance of the marker...CSS selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure."

You'll have to fake the markers as separate elements. The most appropriate way would probably be to use <symbol> and <use> instead. If you want to get fancy, you could even write a Web Component that postitions the <use> elements automatically at the polygon/path vertices and orients them.

Here is one option without <maker> but with animation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198566/fill-shapes-icon-in-svg-path-js/75199633#75199633

You could create a mask that "reveals" the polygone.


.line {
  fill:none;
  fill-opacity:0.46;
  stroke:#3BB0FF;
  stroke-width:8;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}
.linem {
  fill:none;
  fill-opacity:0.46;
  stroke:white;
  stroke-width:32;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  animation: draw 5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
   
   
.marker-circle {
  fill:#FF4F4F;
  fill-opacity:1;
  background-color: red;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  <defs>
    <marker class="marker" id="marker" markerWidth="4"
      markerHeight="4" refX="2" refY="2">
      <circle class="marker-circle" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" />
    </marker>
    <mask id="m1">
      <polygon class="linem" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49"
        pathLength="2000" stroke="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <polygon class="line" mask="url(#m1)"
    points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49"
    marker-start="url(#marker)" marker-mid="url(#marker)" pathLength="2000" />
</svg>




You could animate the points attribute on a second ploygon, so that it gets more and more "points". The timing is something that needs to be done by guessing...


.line {
  fill:none;
  fill-opacity:0.46;
  stroke:#3BB0FF;
  stroke-width:8;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  animation: draw 5s infinite linear;
}
.line2 {
  fill:none;
  fill-opacity:0.46;
  stroke:transparent;
  stroke-width:8;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
   
   
.marker-circle {
  fill:#FF4F4F;
  fill-opacity:1;
  background-color: red;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
 <defs>
   <marker class="marker" id="marker" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" refX="2" refY="2">
   <circle class="marker-circle" cx="2" cy="2" r="2" />
   </marker>
  </defs>
<polygon class="line" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49" pathLength="2000" />
<polygon class="line2" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49" marker-start="url(#marker)" marker-mid="url(#marker)" pathLength="2000">
<animate attributeName="points"
      values="266.14,191.92;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49;
      266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49"
      keyTimes="0;.11;.2;.28;.45;.62;.75;.88;1"
      dur="5s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
</polygon>
</svg>



